# Pure CSS Dropdown Menus are centered on the left margin when I want them fully centered

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, centering

As the title says, I have drop-downs on my webpage (templates because I want to get them right first) and they have aligned themselves centered with their parent on the left margin. No matter what I try, I cannot get them all to center correctly without changing any of the widths or heights of the objects. I need the block links within the nav bar to stay the same size so that they only translate if the word is hovered over. Is there any way to fix this and keep everything else the same?

[Link to my Site](http://ryanjdavid.x10host.com/)

[HTML and CSS](http://goo.gl/YB6zPK) (Can't Seem to get it to work on JSFiddle...)

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to use `absolute` attribute for setting width from `left` and `right` dynamically.

You can see by just changing your css to follwing.

(Note! use left and right instead of width.)

```
nav {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style: none;
  height: 80px;
  left: 275px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing this is by adding **position: relative** to the following selector

```
nav ul li {
   width: auto;
   list-style: inside none none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 33px;
   height: 16px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   left: 0px;
   margin-left: 33px;
   position: relative;
}
```

And I will position the overview.ul with left:-25% inside like this

```
nav li ul {
    height: 70px;
    width: 102px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    left: -25%;    
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I see them in the center now. Hope it help